# Abstract class + mixin + multiple inheritance in python

Tags: python, abstract-class, multiple-inheritance, mixins

So, I think the code probably explains what I'm trying to do better than I can in words, so here goes:

```
import abc

class foo(object):
    __metaclass__ = abc.ABCMeta
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def bar(self):
        pass


class bar_for_foo_mixin(object):
    def bar(self):
        print "This should satisfy the abstract method requirement"


class myfoo(foo, bar_for_foo_mixin):
    def __init__(self):
        print "myfoo __init__ called"
        self.bar()

obj = myfoo()
```

The result:

```
TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class myfoo with abstract methods bar
```

I'm trying to get the mixin class to satisfy the requirements of the abstract/interface class. What am I missing?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Shouldn't the inheritance be the other way round? In the MRO `foo` currently comes before `bar_for_foo_mixin`, and then rightfully complains. With `class myfoo(bar_for_foo_mixin, foo)` it should work.

And I am not sure if your class design is the right way to do it. Since you use a mixin for implementing `bar` it might be better not to derive from foo and just register it with the 'foo' class (i.e. `foo.register(myfoo)`). But this is just my gut feeling.

For completeness, here is the [documentation for ABCs](http://docs.python.org/library/abc.html).

Comment: Good call, changing the order of inheritance does the trick. 

P.S. the code was simplified to illustrate a point. My real world scenario is much more complex with lots of potential mixins and lots of myfoos.

Answer (score 1):

i think (tested in similar case) that reversing the baseclasses works:

```
class myfoo(bar_for_foo_mixin, foo):
    def __init__(self):
        print "myfoo __init__ called"
        self.bar()
```

so in the mro() it would find a concrete version of bar() before it finds the abstract one. No idea if this is actually what happens in the background though.

Cheers, Lars

PS: the code that worked in python 2.7 (python 3 has a different way to set metaclasses) was:

```
class A(object):
    __metaclass__ = abc.ABCMeta

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def do(self):
        pass

class B(object):
    def do(self):
        print "do"

class C(B, A):
    pass

c = C()
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer.  In  py27, your code that worked does indeed enforce the presence of `do()` in class `C`.  However, in py3 (I only tested in py35), this is no longer the case.  In class `B` you can replace the body with `pass`, and instance `c` will happily be created.  Do you know why this might be?

Comment: @cjrh: do you mean the body of B or the body of B.do? If the first, it would be really strange because it would sort of defy the purpose of abc's ..

Comment: Just try your code under "PS: the code that worked was", but change `B` to `class B(object): pass`.  You will see that instance `c` is successfully created.  I tried on Python 3.6, same result.

Comment: Ok, I see what's going on. `__metaclass__` is no longer how you declare a metaclass in Python 3.  Instead you have to specify the metaclass in the class args, e.g., `class A(metaclass=abc.ABCMeta): <etc>`. Then it works as for Python 2.

Comment: check, added to answer