# Mix-in of abstract class and namedtuple

Tags: python

I want to define a mix-in of a namedtuple and a base class with defines and [abstract method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/abc.html#abc.abstractmethod):

```
import abc
import collections

class A(object):
    __metaclass__ = abc.ABCMeta

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def do(self):
        print("U Can't Touch This")

B = collections.namedtuple('B', 'x, y')

class C(B, A):
    pass

c = C(x=3, y=4)
print(c)
c.do()
```

From what I understand reading the docs and [other examples I have seen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/825945/abstract-class-mixin-multiple-inheritance-in-python), `c.do()` should raise an error, as class C does not implement `do()`. However, when I run it... it works:

```
B(x=3, y=4)
U Can't Touch This
```

I must be overlooking something.

Comment: What version of python are you using? Metaclasses are invoked in different, incompatible ways in python 2 versus python 3. If you are using python 3 your class isn't actually an abstract class.

Comment: I tried this with both Python 2 and 3. Same behavior.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you take a look at the method resolution order of `C` you see that `B` comes before `A` in that list. That means when you instantiate `C` the `__new__` method of `B` will be called first.

This is the implementation of `namedtuple.__new__`

```
def __new__(_cls, {arg_list}):
    'Create new instance of {typename}({arg_list})'
    return _tuple.__new__(_cls, ({arg_list}))
```

You can see that it does not support cooperative inheritance, because it breaks the chain and simply calls `tuple`s `__new__` method. Like this the <s>`ABCMeta.__new__`</s> **method that checks for abstract methods** is never executed (where ever that is) and it can't check for abstract methods. So the instantiation does not fail.

I thought inverting the MRO would solve that problem, but it strangely did not. I'm gonna investigate a bit more and update this answer.

Comment: Probably inverting MRO doesn't matter because `B` implements `__new__` and `A` does not.

Comment: but both `namedtuple` and `ABCMeta` have a `__new__` method. Isn't MRO depth first search like?

Comment: Kinda. See this example:
`>>> class X(B,A):
...   pass
... 
>>> X.__mro__
(<class '__main__.X'>, <class '__main__.B'>, <type 'tuple'>, <class '__main__.A'>, <type 'object'>)
>>> 
>>> class Y(A,B):
...   pass
... 
>>> Y.__mro__
(<class '__main__.Y'>, <class '__main__.A'>, <class '__main__.B'>, <type 'tuple'>, <type 'object'>)`. Either way tuple is called first, because ultimately they both derive from object.

Comment: ABCMeta is a type. It's `__new__` function is only called when a class is created, not when an object is created.

Comment: The check for abstract methods occurs in `object.__new__`. Since the class also derives from tuple (which derives from object), then `tuple.__new__` is always invoked in preference to `object.__new__`. And `tuple.__new__` doesn't check for abstract methods. So it's impossible to have an abstract tuple subclass. A possible bug.

Comment: Yeah, I got confused, of course `ABCMeta.__new__` is invoked at a different time. But I still don't understand how the check for abstract methods can be done in `object.__new__`. Is there code to check that? And why is it in `object.__new__` and not in `ABCMeta.__call__` which would make sense to me.

Comment: It is possible to have abstract classes, just not to instantiate them. As such, the check can't be done by `ABCMeta` -- as it is only invoked at class creation time. At class creation, `ABCMeta` sets a flag on the class saying that it is abstract -- https://github.com/python-git/python/blob/715a6e5035bb21ac49382772076ec4c630d6e960/Objects/typeobject.c#L321 .  This is checked for by `object.__new__` at object creation time -- https://github.com/python-git/python/blob/715a6e5035bb21ac49382772076ec4c630d6e960/Objects/typeobject.c#L2876