# Create an abstract class over namedtuples of Counters

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to create several classes, each a [`namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) of [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)s.
My attempt at abstracting identical methods is:

```py
import collections

class NamedCounters():
    "Collect stats for saving to disk."
    def __new__(cls):
        return super().__new__(cls,**{f:collections.Counter() for f in cls._fields})

    def note(self, val):
        "New observation."
        raise NotImplementedError("NamedCounters.note",self,val)

    def as_dict(self):
        "Convert to a dict for saving to file."
        return {n:c.most_common() for n,c in self._asdict().items()}

    @classmethod
    def of_iter(cls, it):
        "Collect stats on all records"
        ret = cls()
        for val in it:
            ret.note(val)
        return ret

    @classmethod
    def of_dict(cls, di):
        "Convert from the dict read from a file."
        ret = cls()
        for f in cls._fields:
            getattr(ret,f).update(dict(di.get(f,[])))
        return ret


def f(d):
    return len(d)+1

class Stat1(NamedCounters, collections.namedtuple("Stat1",["a","b"])):
    def note(self, val):
        self.a[val["asdf"]] += 1
        self.b[f(val)] += 1

def z(d):
    return len(d)+2

class Stat2(NamedCounters, collections.namedtuple("Stat2",["c","d"])):
    def note(self, val):
        self.c[val["qwer"]] += 1
        self.d[z(val)] += 1
```

And it does appear to work:

```py
>>> s1 = Stat1.of_iter([{"asdf":"q"}, {"asdf":"z"}])
>>> s1
Stat1(a=Counter({'q': 1, 'z': 1}), b=Counter({2: 2}))
>>> s1 == Stat1.of_dict(s1.as_dict())
True
>>> s2 = Stat2.of_iter([{"qwer":"d"}, {"qwer":"x"}])
>>> s2
Stat2(c=Counter({'d': 1, 'x': 1}), d=Counter({3: 2}))
>>> s2 == Stat2.of_dict(s2.as_dict())
True
```

What I do *not* like about this approach is that
`NamedCounters` uses `_fields` and `_asdict` which come from [`namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple).
It would be nice if `NamedCounters` inherited from another ("official") class that provided those.
My main problem is that `pylint` complains about `NamedCounters` but *not* about this `class Bad` which forgot to inherit from [`namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple):

```py
class Bad(NamedCounters):
    def note(self, val):
        print(val,self)
```

Any suggestions?

(See also [Mix-in of abstract class and namedtuple](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35267954/850781) and [Abstract class + mixin + multiple inheritance in python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/825945/850781))

Comment: These are official. Namedtuple breaks the single underscore convention for it's public API

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: I know, that's not the issue

Comment: So what is the issue? Didn't you explicitly state: "What I do not like about this approach is that DataStat uses _fields and _asdict which come from namedtuple. "

Comment: Please see edit - I am unhappy that I use those methods _without clear justification_.